crear un Mixed Chart o Chart composition en react
quiero crear un grafico combinado de columnas agrupadas y lineas en react, en el eje x, debe tener los meses del año, cada mes debe tener 3 columnas agrupadas, las columnas serán ev, ac, pv, es decir en el año 2024 debe contener los meses de enero a diciembre, y cada mes debe tener sus columnas agrupadas, lo mismo con el año 2025, 2026, etc. Adicional, las lineas deben obedecer a las variables ev acumulado, ac acumulado, pv acumulado y sigue el mismo patron de las barras, es decir, cada mes esas lineas tendrán su valor diferente, porque tanto las variables ev, ac, pv, ev acumulado, ac acumulado, pv acumulado cambian por mes.
import { BarPlot } from '@mui/x-charts/BarChart';
import { LinePlot } from '@mui/x-charts/LineChart';
import { ChartContainer } from '@mui/x-charts/ChartContainer';
import { AllSeriesType } from '@mui/x-charts/models';
import { ChartsXAxis } from '@mui/x-charts/ChartsXAxis';
import { ChartsYAxis } from '@mui/x-charts/ChartsYAxis';
import { ChartsLegend } from '@mui/x-charts';

const series = [
    {
        type: 'bar',
        yAxisKey: 'eco',
        color: 'gray',
        data: [4, 3, 5]
    },
    {
        type: 'bar',
        yAxisKey: 'eco',
        color: '#2B4F92',
        data: [1, 6, 3] 
        
    },
    {
        type: 'bar',
        yAxisKey: 'eco',
        color: '#DD3D2B',
        data: [2, 5, 6] 
    },
    {
        type: 'line',
        yAxisKey: 'pib',
        color: '#D61600',
        data: [1000, 1500, 3000],
    },
    {
        type: 'line',
        yAxisKey: 'pib',
        color: '#002C7C',
        data: [1200, 2100, 3500],
    },
    {
        type: 'line',
        yAxisKey: 'pib',
        color: 'green',
        data: [0, 2500, 3000],
    },
] as AllSeriesType[];

export default function BarLine() {
    return (
        <ChartContainer
            series={series}
            width={600}
            height={200}
            xAxis={[
                {
                    id: '2024',
                    data: ['jul', 'ago', 'set'],
                    scaleType: 'band',
                },
            ]}
            yAxis={[
                {
                    id: 'eco',
                    scaleType: 'linear',
                },
                {
                    id: 'pib',
                    scaleType: 'linear',
                },
            ]}
        >
            <BarPlot />
            <LinePlot />
            <ChartsXAxis label="2024" position="bottom" axisId='2024'/>
            <ChartsLegend direction="row" />
            <ChartsYAxis position="left" axisId="eco" />
            <ChartsYAxis label='acumulado' position="right" axisId="pib" />
        </ChartContainer>
    );
}


Esto es lo que voy haciendo pero solo puedo hacerlo con un año, con varios años no sé como modificarlo, estoy usando charts de material ui:

Lo que deseo hacer es algo así:


hola, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

que has intentado (codigo) para hacer lo que indicas?

Hola Diego, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Primero verifica si en la documentación mui hay ejemplos como el que quieres implementar, depende de que tan configurable sean las props de ese componente mui , en especifico la propiedad xAxis
